# Multi valued function graph in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is my first script in matlab. **( I cannot use functions)**

Let's say I have a vector of time instants

```
t = [0:999]*1e-5;   %vector of time instants
```

And my function is `m`

This is the part where it is implemented:

```
if (t >= 0)
    if t <= to/3
        m = 1;
    elseif (t <= 2*to/3)
        m = -2;
    end     
else
    m = 0;
end
```

As I realised, m has only one value equal to 1.

How is this possible to have a `1x1000` value here? Where for values of **t** from `0 to to/3 -> m = 1`, `to/3 to 2*to/3 -> m = -2`and `else m=0`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function on each element of an array using `arrayfun` like the following:

```
arrayfun(@(x) m(x), t)
%or 
arrayfun(@m, t)
```

You can find the details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). Also, you can implement your function like the following:

```
function result = m(t)
result = t;
result(t >= 0 && t <= to/3) = 1;
result(t > to/3 && t <= 2*to/3) = -2;
result(t < 0) = 0;
```

then call the function `m` on `t` such as `m(t)`.